# Google.Analytics.Data.V1Alpha - property "daterange" read only

Tags: vb.net, google-analytics, google-api-dotnet-client, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries
I have run the sample code of the quickstart in c# and this works fine.
But I want to use it in an older project that's written in vb.net.

when I create the RunReportRequest object, the properties seem to be readonly...

```
            Dim entity As New Entity()
            entity.PropertyId = propertyId

            Dim m As New Metric
            m.Name = "activeUsers"

            Dim metrics = New Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField(Of Metric)
            metrics.Add(m)

            Dim d As New Dimension
            d.Name = "city"

            Dim dimensions As New Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField(Of Dimension)
            dimensions.Add(d)

            Dim r As New DateRange
            r.StartDate = "2021-01-01"
            r.EndDate = "2021-04-31"

            Dim range As New Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField(Of DateRange)
            range.Add(r)

            Dim request As New RunReportRequest
            With request
                .Entity = entity
                .Dimensions = dimensions
                .Metrics = metrics
                .DateRanges = range
            End With
```

when I hit F5 on the "RunReportRequest" object:

```
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Descriptor As MessageDescriptor
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property Parser As MessageParser(Of RunReportRequest)
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     Date ranges of data to read. If multiple date ranges are requested, each response
        '     row will contain a zero based date range index. If two date ranges overlap, the
        '     event data for the overlapping days is included in the response rows for both
        '     date ranges. In a cohort request, this `dateRanges` must be unspecified.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public ReadOnly Property DateRanges As RepeatedField(Of DateRange)
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     The row count of the start row. The first row is counted as row 0. To learn more
        '     about this pagination parameter, see [Pagination](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#pagination).
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property Offset As Long
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     The number of rows to return. If unspecified, 10 rows are returned. If -1, all
        '     rows are returned. To learn more about this pagination parameter, see [Pagination](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#pagination).
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property Limit As Long
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     A currency code in ISO4217 format, such as "AED", "USD", "JPY". If the field
        '     is empty, the report uses the entity's default currency.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property CurrencyCode As String
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     The filter clause of dimensions. Dimensions must be requested to be used in this
        '     filter. Metrics cannot be used in this filter.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property DimensionFilter As FilterExpression
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     The filter clause of metrics. Applied at post aggregation phase, similar to SQL
        '     having-clause. Metrics must be requested to be used in this filter. Dimensions
        '     cannot be used in this filter.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property MetricFilter As FilterExpression
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     Specifies how rows are ordered in the response.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public ReadOnly Property OrderBys As RepeatedField(Of OrderBy)
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     Cohort group associated with this request. If there is a cohort group in the
        '     request the 'cohort' dimension must be present.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property CohortSpec As CohortSpec
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     Aggregation of metrics. Aggregated metric values will be shown in rows where
        '     the dimension_values are set to "RESERVED_(MetricAggregation)".
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public ReadOnly Property MetricAggregations As RepeatedField(Of MetricAggregation)
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     The metrics requested and displayed.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public ReadOnly Property Metrics As RepeatedField(Of Metric)
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     Toggles whether to return the current state of this Analytics Property's quota.
        '     Quota is returned in [PropertyQuota](#PropertyQuota).
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property ReturnPropertyQuota As Boolean
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     A property whose events are tracked. Within a batch request, this entity should
        '     either be unspecified or consistent with the batch-level entity.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property Entity As Entity
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     If false or unspecified, each row with all metrics equal to 0 will not be returned.
        '     If true, these rows will be returned if they are not separately removed by a
        '     filter.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Property KeepEmptyRows As Boolean
        '
        ' Summary:
        '     The dimensions requested and displayed.
        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public ReadOnly Property Dimensions As RepeatedField(Of Dimension)
```

I have installed this version :
Install-Package Google.Analytics.Data.V1Alpha -Version 1.0.0-alpha01

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not images of your code.

Comment: you might want to look at  Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta

Comment: in v1beta, the properties are readonly as well

Comment: That's the one you want to use. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet  I will be putting up some tutorials on this soon. Hopefully next week but i will be doing C# with luck you can covert them to VB without to much trouble.

Comment: is there a package I can install with nuget or package manager console?

Comment: you already have its Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta,  The following is working with .net 5 and C#.

```
        var client = await BetaAnalyticsDataClient.CreateAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        var request = new RunReportRequest
        {
            Property = "properties/" + PropertyId,
            Dimensions = {new Dimension {Name = "city"},},
            Metrics = {new Metric {Name = "activeUsers"},},
            DateRanges = {new DateRange {StartDate = "2020-03-31", EndDate = "today"},},
        };

        var response = await client.RunReportAsync(request);

        Console.WriteLine("Report result:");

        foreach (var row in response.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row.DimensionValues[0].Value, row.MetricValues[0].Value);
        }
```

Comment: unfortunatly, changing the complete existing project from vb to c# is not an option :(

Comment: You should be able to load a C# library into your VB project and then just alter the code.   Assuming that is that you mean Vb .net other wise you will need to code your own library.

Comment: I already did that but I cannot set the metric and dimension property because they are marked as readonly. I don't know why that is, but the property Entity is not readonly

Comment: This peace of code just save my day. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

After suffering from the exact same confusion as OP, [this comment from Jon Skeet](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/5644#issuecomment-736442969) over on GitHub finally led me to the solution.

```
Dim request = New RunReportRequest() With {
    .Property = "properties/" & propertyId
}
request.Metrics.Add(metrics)
request.Dimensions.Add(dimensions)
request.DateRanges.Add(range)
```